# how to highlight the sidebar menu when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar col-md-3">
<aside class="widget menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepHeading" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepHeading_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblHeadingId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <li class="parent">
                        <a id="anchHeading" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <span id="spanHeading" runat="server" class="open-sub"></span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "module") %></a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="RepSubHeading" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <a id="anchSubHeading" runat="server" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "link") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "property") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<!-- .menu-->
```

I want to add highlight color on sidebar whenever it is clicked. Kindly tell me what should I change in my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar ul li ul li').click(function () {
        $('#sidebar ul li ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    });
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation on jQuery please..
Here the example of closest:
http://jsfiddle.net/pd85b4zb/
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to highlight it on click event of "href" tag or "li" tag? If you want to highlight it on link click try followings.

Update your sub href tag like this (just give a class name to your sub links)

```
<a id="anchSubHeading" runat="server" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "link") %>' class="subLink"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "property") %></a>
```

Then update your script like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar .subLink').click(function () {
        $('#sidebar .subLink').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    });
});
```